# Enforce that all subclasses implement a given type class

Tags: scala

Given a superclass or trait, and assuming an open hierarchy, how can I enforce that all extending classes implement a particular type class?

For instance, assuming the type class `Default`

```
trait Default[T] { def default: T }
```

and some trait `Super`:

```
trait Super { }
```

I would like to enforce that the following (by itself) is not allowed:

```
class A(val i: Int) extends Super
```

...while the following is:

```
class B(val i: Int) extends Super
implicit val bHasDef = new Default[B] { def default = B(42) }
```

Assuming the above is possible, can I then access the type class evidence for the subtypes from a method within `Super`? I.e, something like:

```
trait Super {
  def magic: Default[this.type] = ???
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hardly think you can enforce that, at least in a simple enough way, maybe it's possible with something more complex like shapeless.

What I would do is add some modifications to the super trait and make it take a self reference to `Default`

```
trait Default[T] { def default: T }

trait Super[T] {
  self: Default[T] =>
}

class B(val i: Int) extends Super[Int] with Default[Int] {
  override def default: Int = ???
}

class A(val i: Int) extends Super[Int] // doesn't compile, needs a Default
```

This should also solve the second part of your question, the disadvantage is that now one trait is bundled to the other.